# How can I remove “uncheckAllText” and * icon from jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget and keep everything else?

Tags: jquery

How can I remove “uncheckAllText” and * icon from jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget and keep everything else?

My Code:

```
$("#DayOftheWeekDropDown").multiselect({
    selectedList:1, 
    height:150, 
    minWidth:200, 
    checkAllText: 'checkAll',  
    uncheckAllText: ''
}).multiselectfilter();
```

I tried the code mentioned above but it still keeps *.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to suggest using css:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then some jQuery using the class of that anchor:

```
$('.ui-multiselect-none').addClass('hidden');
```